# Optimize Oracle query, multiple joins table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize some request to my Oracle Database. I am wondering if I should use indexes, clustered indexes, cluster, hash cluster or simply hints while running the request.

The request in question is the following :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1, T2, T3 
WHERE T1.col1 = T3.col11 AND T2.COL1 = T3.COL12 AND T1.col2 = 1;
```

There is 1,000,000 items in table T1 and T2 and 10,000 items in T3.

I tried using clustered indexes and it seems to work, but I am not sure if it is the most optimized way of doing this.

Any help would be welcomed!

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

I can't modify the request. It needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest that you write the query as a series of explicit `JOIN`s.  In general, you should use explicit `JOIN` and avoid commas in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T1 JOIN
     T3
     ON T1.col1 = T3.col11 JOIN
     T2
     ON T2.COL1 = T3.COL12
WHERE T1.col2 = 1;
```

For this query, you want the following indexes:  `T1(col2, col1)`, `T3(col11, col12)` and `T2(col1)`.

In general, clustered indexes do give a slight performance boost (particular for the index on `T1`, in this case).  But, the much more important gain is from using indexes at all.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I want to know if I could optimize it using external tools (indexes, clustered indexes, cluster, hash cluster or hints).

Comment: @Genevieve . . . I believe the answer addresses that point with the suggested indexes.